# Imgur error 400 Client.uploadString

Tags: c#, imgur

I've a pretty long code to upload to imgur, tried to test it out, got some bugs, fixed them. (Also by the help of this site ofc. ) But now I get an error 400.

This is a part of the code, also where it is happening

```
public static ImgurToken GetToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string pin)
        {
            string Url = "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token/";
            string DataTemplate = "client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=pin&pin={2}";
            string Data = String.Format(DataTemplate, clientId, clientSecret, pin);

            using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
            {
                string ApiResponse = Client.UploadString(Url, Data); //Error 400
                var Deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var Response = Deserializer.DeserializeObject(ApiResponse) as Dictionary<string, object>;

                return new ImgurToken()
                {
                    AccessToken = Convert.ToString(Response["access_token"]),
                    RefreshToken = Convert.ToString(Response["refresh_token"])
                };
            }
        }
```

I think I did the DATA and URL right? It's also states it there on the Imgur API website.

**EDIT:** Just noticed, my pin is empty. Is this right?
**EDIT 2:** I checked a little, my ClientSecret is displayed with a red text, but I'm sure it's correct.

GetPin:

```
public static string GetPin(string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            string Pin = String.Empty;
            string OAuthUrlTemplate = "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={0}&response_type={1}&state={2}";
            string RequestUrl = String.Format(OAuthUrlTemplate, clientId, "pin", "blah");
            return Pin;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [imgur documentation](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2#response_type), the url doesn't have the trailing `/`.  Change it to `https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token` just to be sure.

Additionally, you might have to url encode the `Data` string.  You can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` to do that.

The [http 400 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is typically returned when the request has bad syntax, probably your missing `pin`.  Just make sure that the pin you get from the user is added to the `Data` string and not null or empty.

Comment: What does the ? instead of / does. It does nothing that I see. Also, I added the GetKey class, as you can see it has a String Pin, which is empty. Can you do anything with that?

Comment: @Stepepper ah, I understand better now, I've updated my answer

Comment: Where do I put the HttpUtility?

Comment: Oh, I encoded it by `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Data)` but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Yes I did. Although it does give a red text of the link.